# Triggers with two mutually exclusive actions

Tags: keyforge

Say I have a creature with two "On destroyed" triggers that appear to have mutually exclusive instructions: "archive that card" and "put that card on the top of your deck". Which one will be resolved on this creature's destruction?

Answer (score 1):

Active Player (AP) chooses.

Whenever there are multiple effects to resolve, the AP (whose turn it is at the moment; this may or may not be the owner of the card/effect) chooses the order to resolve the effects.

In the example scenario, whichever effect the AP chooses to resolve first will be the final result. I.e. AP chooses to resolve "Destroyed: Archive" first > the card is now archived > "Destroyed: Place on top of deck" never happens because the card is no longer on the field.

The above actually means that if a card has the lines "Destroyed: Archive" & "Destroyed: Steal 1 Amber", AP can actually decide if the steal happens depending on whether they resolve Archive first or second.

Comment: Are you able to give a link to the official rules where this is stated?

Comment: @PhilipKendall I'll try to scrounge something up later. I just checked through the v13 rulebook and the interaction in the final paragraph isn't stated anywhere. This is what I remember from hours of scouring various forums previously, so I'll need to do the research again.

Comment: Under the "Ability" glossary in the rulebook states "...Abilities on a creature, artifact, or upgrade are only active (and can only be triggered) while that card is in play, unless the ability explicitly references being used from an out-of-play area.", but v13 adds "Once an ability on a card has been triggered, that ability will finish resolving even if the card leaves play." But nowhere in the rulebook does it state whether abilities trigger simultaneously, and then resolve in order of choosing OR if abilities trigger and resolve individually before the next.

Comment: This [community wiki page](https://archonarcana.com/Essay:How_Timing_Works_in_KeyForge) corroborates the example I gave above, although I'm not sure how official this source is, or if it is up to date with any rule changes.

Comment: This [reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/KeyforgeGame/comments/i3yp1a/comment/g0ifwvu/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) had the same confusion I'm having, but the general community consensus is that abilities don't trigger&resolve if the card has left play.

Comment: I think your answer is probably right (and I've upvoted it); it is just slightly surprising to me as an MtG player where there are literally [Comprehensive Rules](https://magic.wizards.com/en/rules) that the same doesn't exist for Keyforge. Maybe things will get better now they're rebooting the game.

Comment: Yeah, the rules in Keyforge definitely leaves a lot to be desired once the interactions get a bit more complicated.